# Radio Buttons with Input Other Option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have here an html code that has a radio button and an input choice. How can i clear the input field when the radio button is selected as well as when the input field was selected, the radio button selected will not be selected anymore.

```js
function loadChoice() {
  a = document.getElementById('load_choice');
  a.checked = true;
}

function regularload() {
  a = document.getElementById('load_choice');
  a.value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <span>3. # ng Bahay kung saan po kayo susunduin</span><br>
  <input type="radio" id="none" onclick="regularload()" name="3. # ng Bahay kung saan po kayo susunduin" value="None">   <label for="none">None</label><br>
  <label for="other" onclick="loadChoice()">Others</label>
  <input type="text" id="load_choice" name="3. # ng Bahay kung saan po kayo susunduin">
</div>
```

Comment: You need javascript for this. Listen to input change on each element and update the others value accordingly. Were you able to try something in that direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution that will work with any number of questions and options (it will work regardless, whether there is another free-text option available or not):

```js
const div=document.querySelector(".form-group"); // get parent of all inputs ...
div.addEventListener("change",ev=>{
 const el=ev.target;
 if(el.type==="radio") div.querySelectorAll("[type=text][name="+el.name+"]").forEach(o=>o.value="");
});
div.addEventListener("input",ev=>{
 const el=ev.target;
 if(el.type==="text") div.querySelectorAll("[type=radio]:checked[name="+el.name+"]").forEach(o=>o.checked=false);
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group"><span>3. # ng Bahay kung saan po kayo susunduin</span><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n3bahay" value="1">one</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n3bahay" value="2">two</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n3bahay" value="3">three</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n3bahay" value="4">four</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="n3bahay" placeholder="other ...">
<hr><span>4. # and another question ...</span><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n4more" value="1">one</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n4more" value="2">two</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n4more" value="3">three</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n4more" value="4">four</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="n4more" placeholder="other ...">
<hr><span>5. # a yes/no question:</span><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n5xtra" value="1">yes</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n5xtra" value="0">no</label>
</div>
```

It works with "delegated event attachment", so, even when further questions were to be added, they would also be handled correctly.

Comment: As did my answer  - However yours give error when typing in the field

Comment: Admittedly there was something missing at first, but I fixed it. The current version definitely works. Whereas yours seems to depend on an `id="none"` being there which would make it difficult to work with multiple questions/answers.

Comment: That can very quickly be changed to `if (tgt.type && tgt.type === "radio")`

Comment: hello sir, i tried you code. this seems to be suitable to my problem as well but when the name of the input includes number or space, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It is generally a good idea to use "sensible names" (no blanks or special characters) for your input fields, but I now changed my code to make it work with any type of characters in it. Try it out!

Answer (score 2):

I gave the wrapper an ID

```js
document.getElementById("bahay").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const {type,id} = e.target;
  const textField = document.getElementById("other");
  const check = document.getElementById("none");
  if (type && type === "radio") textField.value = ""; // or 
  else if (id === "other") check.checked = false;
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="bahay">
  <span>3. # ng Bahay kung saan po kayo susunduin</span><br>
  <label><input type="radio" id="none" name="3. # ng Bahay kung saan po kayo susunduin" value="None">None</label><br>
  <label>Others <input type="text" id="other" name="3. # ng Bahay kung saan po kayo susunduin"></label>
</div>
```

Using any radio but only one function, no need for two event handlers with identical code

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".form-group")
container.addEventListener("input", e => {
  const {type, name} = e.target;
  if (type === "radio") container.querySelectorAll(`input[type=text][name=${name}]`)
    .forEach(textField => textField.value="");
  else if (type === "text") container.querySelectorAll(`input[type=radio][name=${name}]`)
    .forEach(rad => rad.checked=false);
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group"><span>3. # ng Bahay kung saan po kayo susunduin</span><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n3bahay" value="1">one</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n3bahay" value="2">two</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n3bahay" value="3">three</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n3bahay" value="4">four</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="n3bahay" placeholder="other ...">
  <hr><span>4. # and another question ...</span><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n4more" value="1">one</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n4more" value="2">two</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n4more" value="3">three</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n4more" value="4">four</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="n4more" placeholder="other ...">
  <hr><span>5. # a yes/no question:</span><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n5xtra" value="1">yes</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="n5xtra" value="0">no</label>
</div>
```

Comment: i've forgot to add the script in the question sir, does the checkbox allow only one option only? thanks for helping sir

Comment: My script can handle any number of fields

Comment: I am imitation the "other" option in the google forms in the radio button fields. Is it possible sir?

Comment: You can use a radio or a checkbox, but a user would expect a checkbox